# Move camera so that selected object is in focus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity scene with 6000+ game objects (text meshes) that are searchable, and when the user searches for one, I want the camera to zoom in and focus on that object. I've been using LookAt to have the camera "look at" the searched object, however the camera still doesn't align with the object, it just looks at it from a distance. I would like the camera to move in a way such that when a string is searched, the corresponding text mesh is in the center of the screen, and zoomed in on/focused on. What would be the best way to put an object in the center of the screen (or rather move the camera so that it looks like that happened)?

Comment: You could simply set the cameras position to be the same as the respective objects' position (x and y) and vary the z for distance.

Comment: Thats one thing that I tried, however the text meshes' positions vary, and they are set up in a circular fashion, so the axis (x,y,or z) that would need to be varied changes based on the search input.

Answer (score 0):

Make your text mesh a child node of the camera gameObject. Then adjust the transformation of the node to put it in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cinemachine, and change "Look At" to the object as needed (in the virtual camera)

[CM Vcam Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCBYc.png)